# Confused about plotting interpolated 2D data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have some unstructured 2D data that I would like to interpolate on a unit offset grid (ie grid indices start at 1 not 0) using `scipy` and plot using `matplotlib`.  The code is below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

#         X  Y   Z
data = [[ 9, 2, 2.0],
        [ 3, 3, 5.0],
        [ 6, 4, 1.0],
        [ 2, 6, 3.0],
        [10, 7, 4.5],
        [ 5, 8, 2.0]]

data = np.array(data)
coords = data[:, 0:2]
zvals  = data[:, 2]

# Create the grid on which to interpolate (unit offset)

nx = 10
ny = 10
x = np.arange(nx)
x += 1
y = np.arange(ny)
y += 1

grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')

# Interpolate

grid_z1 = scipy.interpolate.griddata(coords, zvals, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')

# Plot the results

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(grid_z1)
plt.plot(coords[:,0], coords[:,1], 'k.', ms=10)

plt.show()
```

The point data seem to be in the right place but `matplotlib` seems to be plotting the gridded data as zero-offset not unit-offset.  I am obviously missing something - just not sure what.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "matplotlib seems to be plotting the gridded data as zero-offset not unit-offset"?

Comment: I mean that the limits on the x and y axes should be from 1 to 10 not 0 to 9 as the plot shows, corresponding to the values of x and y that I used to make the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(grid_z1, origin='lower', extent=[1, 10, 1, 10])
plt.plot(coords[:,0], coords[:,1], 'k.', ms=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

IIUC, you want to define `xlim` and `ylim` equal to the plot and not the heatmap:

```
plt.plot(coords[:,0], coords[:,1], 'k.', ms=10)
ax = plt.gca()
xlim, ylim = ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()
plt.imshow(grid_z1)
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Corralien - I don't think I explained properly.  I am expecting to see the shaded area overlap with the dots.  For example, in your plot cell (4, 7) should overlap with the dot at cell (5, 8) because the data is defined at (5,8) not (4, 7)

Comment: @PetGriffin. Don't forget you don't have the same frame of reference between your grid (1->10) and matplotlib (0->9) because you added 1 to your meshgrid. Matplotlib doesn't care about your reference in the matrix, it consider theorigin to (0, 0). You have to define a custom extent for imshow => extent=(1, 10, 1, 10)